# Getting General run error while trying to import Excel sheet into HP UFT 12.02

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

On HP UFT 12.02, While trying to import an Excel sheet into the local data sheet I am getting *"General run error"*. The excel sheet path given is also correct. Apart from this I am getting another error saying *"UFT resources are running low"*.

The statement I am using is as follows.

`DataTable.ImportSheet TestCaseSheetPath,TestScenarioName,TestScenarioName`.

This snip was working fine until I used another statement to write back to the Excel sheet yesterday as follows.

`DataTable.Value("str_MessageID",TestDataSheet) = messageID
 DataTable.ExportSheet Environment.Value("TestCaseSheetPath"),TestDataSheet`.

The above snip executed once and since then I have been getting the error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is the size of the excel sheet you are trying to import?

Comment: DataTable.ExportSheet Environment.Value("TestCaseSheetPath"),"Action1",TestDataSheet. use this statement insated of DataTable.ExportSheet Environment.Value("TestCaseSheetPath"),TestDataSheet and see it works or not. Here the 'Action1' is your local one.

Comment: @Gurman its 35151kb of size.

Comment: Are you really having that large chunk of data? Is the excel file saved in `.xls` format or `.xlsx`? I had once faced a similar issue. Then, I exported the data to an excel file in `xlsx` format rather than in the `xls` format which solved this issue(weird, right?). Find more info [HERE](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UFT-Practitioners-Forum/QTP-Data-table-export-causes-the-size-of-MS-excel-file-to-shoot/td-p/299005)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with an issue where UFT would throw an General Error. The original Excel file was saved as XLSX on my system and I had it XLS in the script.

Updating to XLSX fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: Is your issue related to the question? Please clarify it [edit]ing your answer. Don't include expressions like `I stuck`, `I had another problem which I fixed doing...`, but instead, `do x, y and z`.